# How to change default scale of the added objects?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, transforms

I noticed that when I add new object it is very tiny compared to existing objects. In the example on the photo it is 10 times smaller.

Viewport scale is 0.001

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: does this happen ina certain scene?
Or in  every scene you create?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by every scene I create? I don't create any scenes.

Answer (score 1):

The default `Viewport Scale` in Blender is and should be 1 (not 0.001). Reasons follow.
There are legitimate reasons to reset the `Viewport Scale` to something much larger or smaller, but unless you don't have or know these reasons, it should not be altered, otherwise you might experience some serious strange behaviour.

## Understanding Viewport Scale

In Blender, the default unit of the standard cube is 1 meter.
Since the default cube has an extent of 1 meter in all directions, positive and negative, the edge length of the default cube is 2 meters.

If you want to create scenes in Blender whose scales are significantly larger or smaller than in the normal world, then it is recommended to adjust the `Viewort Scale`.  This is because this scale is used as a reference for many aspects of the Blender environment, including physics simulations, rendering settings, camera phsysics (i.e. optics), and real-world scale modeling. Again, having "things" in the wrong scale may cause problems, or otherwise: If you try to scale your micro-world into the standard 1-meter world, you will have to account for a whole bunch of other things to "get right", which could resolve quite easily if you instead had chosen the correct scale of your world.

This `Viewport Scale` is by default 1.
When you import or add objects into Blender with a "strange" `Viewport Scale`, they may appear much smaller or larger because they are typically created with real-world measurements in mind.

## Fix

### Problem in a certain `.blend` file

Your problem may be a problem in one certain scene - you or someone accidentally  or intentional changed the `Viewport Scale` (for what reason ever). If this intention is valid, then stay with it - the benefits may be worth the mentioned sideeffects.
If it's unintentional - go change it back to normal!
If this behavior occurs even in new scenes, then you might unintentionally have changed the default scene of Blender.

### Problem occurs in all new created `.blend` files

You have accidentially changed the default settings in the startup file.

#### You have two choices:

1. In `File => Defaults` you can select `Load Factory Settings`. This will reset all your default settings, you may loose settings th tyou changed intentionally.
2. Or you go to `File => New => General` (= loading your customized Default scene), change the `Viewport Scale`value back to 1, then got to
   `File => Defaults => Save Startup File`, which will write your customized settings with the standard `Viewport Scale` into your startup File.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it doesn't solve my problem. I still don't know how to make new objects to match the size of existing object by default. I have to scale them every time.